# Split the string and append the second and first elements

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to perl scripting. tried following code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
our $sep = "-";

open my $data, $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open $ARGV[0] for reading: $!";
while( my $line = <$data> )
{
        $line =~ s/]:/\n]:/g;
        my @spl = split(', ', $line);
        $hello = $spl[2].'-'.$spl[1];
        print $hello;
        print "\n";
}
```

My sample input

```
, 1234, task]: 1122
```

My current output

```
task
]: 1122
-1234
```

My expected sample output

```
task-1234]: 1122
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired result can be achieve in many ways. Perhaps [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) is not the best approach in this particular case.

Input sample data have very simple format and can be processed with [regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($fname,$regex);

$regex = qr/^, (\d+), (.+?)]: (\d+)$/;

while( <DATA> )
{
    next if /^\s*$/;
    my @data = $_ =~ /$regex/;
    say "$data[1]-$data[0]\]: $data[2]";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
, 1234, task]: 1122
```

Output

```
task-1234]: 1122
```

Note: replace `<DATA>` with [<>](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop) to process a file specified on command line

Following code sample utilizes [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) to achieve same result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

while( <DATA> )
{
    next if /^\s*$/;
    my @data = split(/[, \]:]+/, $_);
    say "$data[2]-$data[1]\]: $data[3]";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
, 1234, task]: 1122
```

Output

```
task-1234]: 1122
```

You can start learn Perl by Google search [Perl bookshelf](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+bookshelf), although books are dated they still of great value.

Please look at following free book to get upto date programming style

- [Modern Perl](http://www.nylxs.com/docs/modern-perl-fourth-edition_p1_0.pdf)

There are [plenty free perl programming books](https://www.google.com/search?q=perl+free+books) available on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve it, But logic is too bad

```
open my $stack, $ARGV[0] or die "Can't open $ARGV[0] for reading: $!";
while( my $line = <$stack> )
{
        my @spl = split(']:', $line);
        my @spl1 = split(', ', $spl[0]);
        $line = $spl1[2].'-'.$spl1[1]."]:".$spl[1];
        print $line;
        print "\n";
}
```

Expected output

```
task-1234]: 1122
```